# `dsget group` fails with object class does not match command line

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to retrieve information about members of an active directory group using `dsget`. The command retrieves some but not all members (53 of 141). The problem group contains a child group. The same command syntax with other groups not having a child group is successful. [Docs for dsget](http://ss64.com/nt/dsget-group.html) make it clear quering sub groups is expected to work.

```
dsget group "CN=MyGroup,OU=Users and Groups,DC=example,DC=ca" -members -expand -c | dsget user -samid -display

dsget failed:CN=SomeChildGroup,OU=Users and Groups,DC=example,DC=ca:The object class of the target does not match the one specified on the command line.
type dsget /? for help.  samid       display
  dandithe    Danny.Dithers
  adamaca     Adam.Abacus
  sarahso     Sarah.Soother
  colcust     Colin.Custard
```

This is run on a client workstation (win7) from a user account that does not have any domain admin privileges. Adding or removing the `-expand` parameter for recursively querying sub-groups seems to have no effect. Neither does `-c` for continue on error.

Any idea what is wrong and how to work around it? Please keep in mind I have no domain privileges.

Answer (score 4):

I discovered that I was putting the `-c` on the wrong side of the pipe. Or perhaps it should be on both sides. In any case adding it to the right works:

```
set ad_path=CN=MyGroup,OU=Users and Groups,DC=example,DC=ca
dsget group "%ad_path%" -members -expand -c | dsget user -samid -display -c
```

There is still an error, because the child group isn't a user, but it passes over that and keeps going.

Solution found thanks to [Richard Parmiter](http://www.parmiter.com/scripts/2009/01/RP552).

Comment: You may also use `dsquery *` and an LDAP filter to query a specific object category: `dsquery * -filter "(&(objectCategory=person)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=MyGroup,OU=Users and Groups,DC=example,DC=ca)" -limit 0`

Comment: @DavidMakogon What exactly was the reason for rolling back that edit? Seriously... o_O

Comment: Because the change you made materially modified the answer (one with several upvotes). Post your own answer or post a reply in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that some of the objects coming from the `dsget group` are, in fact, groups, yet you are passing them all to `dsget user`.

The simple way to get around this is to send the results of the first command to a file, edit out the group entries and feed the result to the second command.